# If $L_n \rightarrow L \in X^*$ in the weak* sense and $x_n \rightarrow x$ in norm, does $L_n(x_n) \rightarrow L(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual. Let $\{L_n\}$ be a sequence in $X^*$ such that $L_n \rightarrow L$ in the weak* sense, and suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in norm. The question I am working on asks if it is necessarily true that $L_n(x_n) \rightarrow L(x)$.

I believe the answer should be yes. Note that since $L \in X^*$, its norm $|L|$ is bounded. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then weak* convergence implies there exists $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$|L_n(x) - L(x)| < \epsilon/2 \quad \forall n \geq n_1.$$
Similarly, convergence in norm says there exists $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\|x_n - x\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|L|} \quad \forall n \geq n_2.$$
Let $N = \max\{n_1, n_2\}$, then for all $n \geq N$:
$$|L_n(x_n) - L(x)| \leq |L_n(x_n) - L(x_n)| + |L(x_n - x)| \leq |L_n(x_n) - L(x_n)| + |L|\|x_n - x\| \\< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + |L|\frac{\epsilon}{2|L|} = \epsilon.$$

Is this correct or have I made any errors in my proof?

Comment: You likely mean $\max$ instead of $\min$ in the definition of $N$, because you want $x \geq N$ to imply *both* $x \geq n_1$ and $x \geq n_2$, but other than that, this looks OK.  For expository purposes it sometimes helps a reader to include some (maybe logically redundant) recitation of specifics of what you are using, e.g. "because $L_n$ converges weak-star to $L$, there is $n_1$ such that" and "because $x_n$ converges to $x$ in norm, there is $n_2$ such that" instead of "weak-star convergence implies that there is $n_1$ such that" and "convergence in norm says there is $n_2$ such that."

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you for your comment and tips. I have corrected the min/max typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your proof is wrong. First, please don't write $|L|$ for the norm, write $\|L\|$. Next, a very common (but easily fixable) mistake when writing explicit $\epsilon$-$N$ proofs is the choice of $\frac{\epsilon}{2\|L\|}$; if $\|L\|=0$, then this quotient is meaningless. Instead use something like $\frac{\epsilon}{2\|L\|+1}$ (but as you'll see below, this isn't the right choice either... you need $\frac{\epsilon}{2M+1}$, where $M$ is defined below).

Anyway, those were trivial matters. The big issue is that you haven't justified why $|L_n(x_n)-L(x_n)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. You say this can be made less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, but that's not true based only on what you said. Look back at where $n_1$ comes from. This $n_1$ (and hence $N$) depends on the specific point $x$ in the Banach space. The correct way to argue is as follows: for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$,
\begin{align}
|L_n(x_n)-L(x)|&\leq |L_n(x_n)-L_n(x)|+|L_n(x)-L(x)|\\
&\leq \|L_n\|\cdot\|x_n-x\|+|L_n(x)-L(x)|\\
&\leq M\cdot\|x_n-x\|+|L_n(x)-L(x)|,\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where $M:=\sup\limits_{k\in\Bbb{N}}\|L_k\|$.
Note that since $L_k\to L$ in the weak* topology, the sequence of functionals $\{L_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is by definition pointwise convergent, hence pointwise bounded, so by Banach-Steinhaus theorem (i.e uniform boundedness principle), it follows that the sequence of operator norms $\{\|L_k\|\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded as well, and thus the supremum, $M$, above is finite. Now, we can take the limit $n\to\infty$ on the RHS of $(*)$. Both terms vanish by hypothesis (the first due to norm convergence, and second due to weak* convergence); the key difference between my argument and yours is that in mine, the second term is $|L_n(x)-L(x)|$, the point of evaluation is simply $x$, not $x_n$. This proves $L_n(x_n)\to L(x)$.

If you want, you can now transcribe this into an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof, but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my proof, I understand where my errors are now. Do you consider $|L_n(x)-L(x)|$ instead of $|L_n(x_n)-L(x_n)|$ because the point should remain fixed as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @CBBAM yes, and that's what the definition of weak* convergence requires.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Comment: @CBBAM extra fyi: the way you wrote your inequality would be fine if you had the extra assumption that $L_n\to L$ in the strong sense in $X^*$ (i.e $\|L_n-L\|\to 0$). Make sure you know how to continue under this assumption as well (no fancy theorems necessary here).

Comment: I will have to think about that case, but I think it follows because the operator norm gives us a supremum (by definition), so we do not need the $M$ you introduced.

Comment: I mean sure, $\|L_n-L\|\to 0$ implies that the $M$ I introduced is finite (but no, this $M$ as a supremum should not be confused with the supremum in the definition of operator norm!). But I'm saying that even with the way you wrote your inequalities, one can still continue from there to finish off the proof.

Comment: I think I got it. We can use convergence in the operator norm to bound $|L_n(x_n) - L(x_n)|$ by $|L_n - L| \cdot \|x_n\|$, and we know $\|x_n\|$ must be bounded as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $\{x_n\}$ is assumed to be convergent.

Comment: yes that's right.